# How to get programmatically added content as XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose we have WPF element, in code we add content/controls to it.
How do we get the generated content as XAML?

for example in XAML we have:

In code behind:

```
  pLines.Points.Add(new Point(10, 140));
        pLines.Points.Add(new Point(270, 140));
        pLines.Points.Add(new Point(270, 220));
        pLines.Points.Add(new Point(255, 220));
        pLines.Points.Add(new Point(230, 175));
        pLines.Points.Add(new Point(205, 220));
```

Now how to get the generated XAML after the code behind is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613434.aspx) class.

```
var pLines = new Polyline();
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(10, 140));
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(270, 140));
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(270, 220));
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(255, 220));
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(230, 175));
pLines.Points.Add(new Point(205, 220));
string asXaml = XamlWriter.Save(pLines);
//<Polyline Points="10,140 270,140 270,220 255,220 230,175 205,220" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
```